# Updating view with async operation in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, async-await

I'm writing a small internal web app.
I need to do a very long operation (which can take about an hour) at the press of a button and  let the user know once the operation completes with its result.

In other words, I need the button to start the async operation and refresh the view with the results once it is finished (after about an hour run).

Edit: The operation could use some sort of a refresh mechanism in the View. The result can be sent to the view after a small lag (doesn't have to refresh realtime)

Comment: May be you can think about WebSockets implementation(SignalR) in this case

Comment: Have a look at [async await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx), sounds like it might do what you want.

Comment: ASP.NET and IIS were not built to such long Operations. You should post your work to be done somewhere else (a Windows service?) and have the page poll for completion.

Answer (score 3):

You could use SignalR, but that might be a little bit overkill for this. Another option is to set up another controller action which checks if the task has been completed. Then, on the client side, you could use jQuery to make ajax requests to that controller action. When the action comes back as complete you can show an alert or otherwise update the page.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: http://mysite.info/tasks/checkComplete/5,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response == 'true') {
            alert('Task complete');
        }         
    }
});
```

As for what happens on the server side, I don't think this is a case where I would use async/await. If your task is really going to be running for an hour I have a feeling you're going to run into timeout issues, etc. I would have a controller action which is used to start the task, but all it does it put the request to start in the database. I would then have an external "worker" which checks for requests in that database and performs the tasks. Once the task is complete it would update that database entry to mark it as complete. Then the "CheckComplete" controller action from my example above could check the database to see if the task is in fact completed.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I recommend you to take a look at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr), it's not that hard to implement.
You'll have to implement a server on your website, send a message to the server when your long operation is complete, and refresh your view when the message is received.
The tutorials from Microsoft should be clear enough for that.

Answer (score 0):

A low tech solution from the age way before AJAX and WebSockets was to simply continually write data to the response (usually a progress report).

So instead of doing the work asynchronously, you would call something like

```
Response.Write("<script>reportProgress(" + progress + ");</script>"); 
Response.Flush();
```

once in a while. It has its issues, but it might still be a good way if you have to support weird platforms or very old browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Ummm,

I will try to create flag into the server when finished the work.
    In the MVC you can will create a TIMER obj that check, for example each minute, if the server has finished the work, and launch this timer in a new thread that not block the app.

(sorry, for my english).